# GWT: disable all events on some widget

Tags: java, events, gwt

I have some widget which I consider to be disabled. Disabled widget should never process any events. But in fact I have several UIHandlers added to that widget. Such as OnClick, OnKeyPressed, OnKeyDown etc. I dont want to unregister these handlers one by one, and I dont want to add if-clauses to them. Another option is to subclass from that widget and override OnBrowserEvent, but it implies creating another class.

Is it possible to disable all the events related to that widget in one code snippet?

I have googled the following solution:

```
            Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new Event.NativePreviewHandler()
            {
                public void onPreviewNativeEvent(Event.NativePreviewEvent pEvent)
                {
                    final Element target = pEvent.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().cast();

                    // block all events targetted at the children of the composite.
                    if (DOM.isOrHasChild(myWidget.getElement(), target))
                    {
                        pEvent.cancel();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Thats what I want. But unfortunately it doesn't work :) OnFocusEvent, KeyDownEvent still arrive and the corresponding handlers are called.

Is there some short way to accomplish this? GWT 2.5

Comment: Think you will also need to call pEvent.preventDefault()

Comment: There is no such a method, Christian.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had similar problem. To solve it one should add:

```
pEvent.getNativeEvent().preventDefault()
```